# Is it necessary to learn Zend Framework before learning Magento?

Tags: zend-framework, magento

i am newbie in Magento and wants to learn Magento effectively. i know Maegnto is based on zendframe work. i have not worked in Zend framework before.
Is it necessary to learn Zend Framework before learning Magento ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not necessarily required to learn the Zend Framework before.
But it sure helps if you understand the general paradigm of Model View Controller (MVC) to get a better grasp of the system.
While Magento relies heavily on the Zend Framework, it does things its own way in many aspects, so if you want to learn Magento, I would recommend diving right into learning Magento and learning Zend framework on the way where appropriate. 
Good in depth tutorials to get started as a developer are:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: It is important to know zend framework .I faced it.I knew nothing what was that code all about.So i learnt zend now feel better & comfortable with magento

Comment: It's important to learn Zend Framework before Magento to get better understanding while learn it. some libraries which I know extend from Zend Framework Library such as Varien_Db_Select, Varien_Db_Adapter_Mysqli, Varien_Http_Client, etc.

Comment: @JokoWandiro i understand magento to know where and how the url works, what i don't know how to extend things or make new module/extension, would u recommend php or oop

Comment: @Nofel I should revise my comment you can learn Magento without learn Zend Framework, you just need know PHP and check the application and get good books, You should using OOP programming than procedural.

Comment: @JokoWandiro what level, should i be on php? i know OOP much to work in it. But have no idea, how magento extension are created or any other functionality, what do you recommend (i learn php from treehouse). Do you recommend laravel or anything mvc framework?

Comment: @Nofel You should check the application created using procedural or object oriented programming method. If it using OOP then check the structure usually using MVC pattern then check where is Model, View and Controller then modify it if success, you can try to create new page using existing or new Controller.

Comment: @JokoWandiro which books u recommend?

Answer (score -2):

No.

While it would be helpful, I've practically learnt Magento from not knowing anything beyond Python and C#. Programming knowledge and HTML/CSS knowledge is useful, but you don't need to know the in's and out's of the framework to be able to use it.